# Not able to get output result from Microsoft text analytics topic recognition

Tags: python-2.7, azure-hub, text-analytics-api

my `rawdata.json` file

```
{"Inputs":[
    {"Id":"1","Text":"I loved the food at this restaurant"},
    {"Id":"2","Text":"I loved the food at sadthis restaurant"},
    {"Id":"3","Text":"I loved the food at tsadhis restaurant"},
......,   
    {"Id":"100","Text":"I hated the decor"}
],
"StopPhrases":[
    "restaurant", “visitor"
]}
```

i read this file in my module

```
file_path = '/home/sujith/pylzdata/rawdata.json'
f = open(file_path, 'r')
input_texts = f.read()
```

and this

```
print('Starting topic detection.')
uri = base_url + 'text/analytics/v2.0/topics'
req = urllib2.Request(uri, input_texts, headers)
response_headers = urllib2.urlopen(req).info()
uri = response_headers['operation-location']
```

error output

Starting topic detection.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./lzdata.py", line 25, in

```
response_headers = urllib2.urlopen(req).info()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen

```
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open

```
response = meth(req, response)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response

```
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error

```
return self._call_chain(*args)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain

```
result = func(*args)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default

```
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

sources: https://text-analytics-demo.azurewebsites.net/Home/SampleCode, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-apps-text-analytics#topic-detection-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your input format is wrong. Should be `documents` and not `Inputs`:

```
{
     "documents": [  
         {
             "id": "1",
             "text": "First document"
         },
         ...
         {
             "id": "100",
             "text": "Final document"
         }
     ],
     "stopWords": [
         "issue", "error", "user"
     ],
     "stopPhrases": [
         "Microsoft", "Azure"
     ]
}
```

See the following blog post for more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quick-start